# (change) event does not work on select and input elements but does on checkbox Angular 6, Material 6

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ecmascript-6, material-design

**After updating my project from Material v5.2.4 to v6.0.0 and Angular v5.1.2 to v6.0.0, the `(change)` event doesn't work on select and `input type="text"` elements while it does work fine on a checkbox element.**

**Note:** changing the event from `(change)` to `(ngModelChange)` is working perfectly fine for all the above specified elements. Also, the `(change)` event was working just fine before the upgrade on all of them.

**StackBlitz to reproduce the issue => [HERE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-select-change-event?file=app/app.component.html)**

**ng -v command result:**

```
Angular CLI: 6.0.0
Node: 8.11.1
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 6.0.0
... animations, cdk, cli, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core
... forms, http, language-service, material, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.6.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.6.0
@angular-devkit/core              0.6.0
@angular-devkit/schematics        0.6.0
@ngtools/webpack                  6.0.0
@schematics/angular               0.6.0
@schematics/update                0.6.0
rxjs                              6.1.0
typescript                        2.7.2
webpack                           4.6.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`MatSelect` exposes `selectionChange` to emit select's change event, use `selectionChange` event instead of `change` event, see **[APIs](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api#MatSelect)**.

refer **[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-select-change-event-bns973?file=app/app.component.html)**.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer, how we can get the food.ViewValue in your example in typescript side, thanks